# Entity Framework Core 2.0 - Add-Migration doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a new project code-first. When trying to create a migration, using the [Add-Migration Initial -Context LogAuditoriaContext] command, it simply does nothing, doesn't create, doesn't give error, doesn't report anything.

I have already tried to map with FluentAPI on both OnModelCreating() and separate files, the result is the same.

Looking at Output Window, it shows:
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I'm using dot.net core 2.0 and C # 7.2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Output Window. It might give you some hints

Comment: Yeah, I already looked there. How I said, there are none messages. Only: ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: The only time I'm aware of that that command will give absolute no output is if no database schema changes are detected. In other words, it sees it has nothing to do and just exits. Otherwise, you should be getting *something*. Check the PMC window. Also try making a change that will *definitely* require a migration, such as adding a new entity type, add/removing a property, etc. It's possible the change you've made simply can't be "migrated", not all code changes necessarily translate to a database-level change.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, but I am trying to generate the database for the first time, so is not schema changes. What is it PMC Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was the connection string, just change the name of LogAuditoria to LogAuditoriaConnection and its references in Startup and LogAuditoriaContext.

[image]